# Two sided p-value for a discrete distribution is greater than one

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, p-value

Suppose $X_1$ is a random variable. I want to test the hypothesis $$ H_0:X_1\sim \delta_0 \textrm{ vs } H_1:X_1\not \sim \delta_0.$$
Where $\delta_0$ is the Dirac-measure in $0$. As teststatistic I take T(x)=x, if i get the sample $x_1=0$, then I would calculate the p-value through
$$2\cdot\min\{P(T(x_1)\geq T(X_1)|H_0),P(T(x_1)\leq T(X_1)|H_0)\}
=2\cdot\min\{P(0\geq 0|H_0),P(0\leq 0|H_0)\}=2.$$
I don't understand how I can get a p-value over 1, if the p-value is supposed to represent the probability of an " even extremer event regarding T" under the Nullhypothesis. Maybe if the distribution of the teststatistic under the Nullhpothesis is discrete the two sided p-value has to be calculated through
$$ \min \{2\min\{P(T(x_1)\geq T(X_1)|H_0),P(T(x_1)\leq T(X_1)|H_0)\},1\}.$$
In this situation a p-value of 1 would make sense, but I have not found anything about handling p-value's of discrete distributions differently. This example is obviously made up, but I had a simular problem with the Hypergeometric distribution, where suddenly the left an right sided p-value where both greater than 0.5, so the p-value was greater than 1. I would appreciate some guidance, which mistake I made.

Comment: Why would you calculate the p-value this way??  Consider what your critical region is and compute the chance (under $H_0$) that $T(X_1)$ will lie in that region.  Using this basic concept will guarantee you do not obtain an invalid result (barring any computational error, of course).

Comment: Isn't the critical reason defined by the region, where $H_0$ is rejected? In order to get such I region I have to set an $\alpha$ which I didn't do, because the p-value can be calculated without an $\alpha$. Maybe you mean with critical region, the region that is as least as " extreme" (regarding the Teststatistic) as $T(x_1)$ under $H_0$. In this case this would be $\mathbb{R}$, so the p-value would be 1. This is clear, but I considered the above formula standard and am confused that it doesn't hold in all cases.

Comment: Fair enough.  That directs you towards consulting your source for that formula, where you will want to investigate the assumptions it makes.  I suspect it might rule out your example.  It *should* if it's correct!